# Nested hash defined?()

Tags: ruby, hash, defined, hash-of-hashes

What's the most concise way to determine if `@hash[:key1][:key2]` is defined, that does not throw an error if `@hash` or `@hash[:key1]` are nil?

`defined?(@hash[:key1][:key2])` returns True if `@hash[:key1]` exists (it does not determine whether `:key2` is defined)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using ActiveSupport (Rails) or Backports, you can use `try`:

```
@hash[:key1].try(:fetch, :key2)
```

You could even handle `@hash` being `nil`:

```
@hash.try(:fetch, :key1).try(:fetch, :key2)
```

If you want `@hash` to always return a hash for a missing key:

```
@hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = {} }
@hash[:foo] # => {}
```

You could also define this recursive:

```
def recursive_hash
  Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = recursive_hash }
end

@hash = recursive_hash
@hash[:foo][:bar][:blah] = 10
@hash # => {:foo => {:bar => {:blah => 10}}}
```

But to answer your question:

```
module HasNestedKey
  Hash.send(:include, self)
  def has_nested_key?(*args)
    return false unless sub = self[args.shift]
    return true if args.empty?
    sub.respond_to?(:has_nested_key?) and sub.has_nested_key?(*args)
  end
end

@hash.has_nested_key? :key1, :key2
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I am missing something, but if all you care about is concise...why not:

```
@hash && @hash[:key1] && @hash[:key1][:key2]
```

or if you want to save a few characters

```
@hash && (h = @hash[:key1]) && h[:key2]
```

if any part of this fails, it returns `nil` otherwise it returns the value associated with `:key2` or `true`.

The reason the `defined?` returns true even if `:key2` is not there is because it just checks whether the object you are referencing exists, which in that case is the method `[]` which is an alias for the method `fetch` which does exist on the hash `@hash[:key1]` but if that were to return nil, there is no fetch method on `nil` and it would return `nil`.  That being said, if you had to go `n` deep into an embedded hash, at some point it would become more efficient to call:

```
defined?(@hash[:key1][:key2][:key3]) && @hash[:key1][:key2][:key3]
```

Comment: `x = {a:{b:{c:3}}}` `defined?(x[:z]) # => "method"`

Comment: `@hash = {:key1 => true}` `@hash && @hash[:key1] && @hash[:key1][:key2] # => NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for true:TrueClass)`

Answer (score 2):

**Using Hash#fetch**

You can use the [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002849) method with a default of `{}` so that it is safe to call `has_key?` even if the first level key doesn't exist. e.g.

```
!hash.nil? && hash.fetch(key1, {}).has_key?(key2)
```

**Alternative**

Alternatively you can use the conditional operator e.g.

```
!hash.nil? && (hash.has_key?(key1) ? hash[key1].has_key?(key2) : false)
```

i.e. if `hash` doesn't have key `key1` then just return `false` without looking for the second level key. If it does have `key1` then return the result of checking `key1's` value for `key2`.

Also, if you want to check that `hash[key1]'s` value has a `has_key?` method before calling it:

```
!hash.nil? && (hash.has_key?(key1) ? hash[key1].respond_to?(:has_key?) &&
   hash[key1].has_key?(key2) : false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@hash[:key1].has_key? :key2
```

Comment: This will raise `NoMethodError: undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass` if `@hash` doesn't have a value for `:key1`

Comment: @Wayne yep, `fetch` is one of the approaches I suggested in my answer. See below (or above depending on SO's randomizer!)

Comment: @mikej, You're right.  Sorry for being redundant.  I've nuked my comment, since it was not too useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about distinguishing nonexistent `@hash[:key1][:key2]` (at any of 3 levels) from `@hash[:key1][:key2] == nil`, this is quite clean and works for any depth:

```
[:key1,:key2].inject(hash){|h,k| h && h[k]}
```

If you want `nil` to be treated as existing, use this instead:

```
(hash[:key1].has_key?(:key2) rescue false)
```

Comment: Abusing exceptions for normal program flow is a code smell, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, one that I just discovered, is to extend Hash with a `seek` method. Technique comes from [Corey O'Daniel](http://coryodaniel.com/index.php/2009/12/30/ruby-getting-deeply-nested-values-from-a-hash-in-one-line-of-code/comment-page-1/#comment-534).

Stick this in an initializer:

```
class Hash
  def seek(*_keys_)
    last_level    = self
    sought_value  = nil

    _keys_.each_with_index do |_key_, _idx_|
      if last_level.is_a?(Hash) && last_level.has_key?(_key_)
        if _idx_ + 1 == _keys_.length
          sought_value = last_level[_key_]
        else                   
          last_level = last_level[_key_]
        end
      else 
        break
      end
    end

    sought_value
  end 
end
```

Then just call:

```
@key_i_need = @hash.seek :one, :two, :three
```

You'll get the value, or nil if it doesn't exist.