# Test Ruby multi dimensional hash

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a clean way to avoid calling a method on nil in a nested params hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429790/is-there-a-clean-way-to-avoid-calling-a-method-on-nil-in-a-nested-params-hash)

Is there an easy way to check if a value in a multi dimensional hash is set without catching the NoMethodException?

Ex.:

```
do_x if cat['level1']['level2']['level3'] != 'value'
```

The problem is, that 'level2' might not even exist, so the receiver is nil.

In PHP you can just put an '@' in front to suppress the error.

In Ruby I would have to wrap the check in a begin-rescue block.

Is there a quick solution like in PHP?

Comment: multi-duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5429790/188031

Answer (score 1):

```
do_x if cat['level1']['level2']['level3'] != 'value' rescue nil
```

This is the inline `rescue`. The problem is that it can hide bugs since it rescues from *any* `RuntimeError`. You really should use proper `begin`-`rescue` blocks instead:

```
begin
  do_x if cat['level1']['level2']['level3'] != 'value'
rescue NoMethodError => error
  puts error.message
end
```

With that said, why not eliminate the nesting and avoid the issue altogether?

```
do_x if cat['level1.level2.level3'] != 'value'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can redefine [] on nil so it behaves like you want before you run your code:

```
class NilClass
  def[](key)
    nil
  end
end
```

Comment: While this could work here, I would strongly advise you not to do this, as this will very effectively hide real bugs and make it a nightmare to debug any sufficiently complex application. Having errors when things break is generally a good thing :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyHash < Hash
  def initialize(levels=0)
    super()
    self.default = MyHash.new(levels-1) if levels > 1
  end
end

cat = MyHash.new(3)

cat['level1']                     #=> {}
cat['level1']['level2']           #=> {}
cat['level1']['level2']['level3'] #=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use try method instead of rescue.
`do_x if cat['level1'].try(:[], 'level2').try(:[], 'level3')` so if do_x raises an exception it won't be rescued and you will actually see if something goes wrong inside do_x