# Ruby check if nil before calling method

Tags: ruby, null

I have a string in Ruby on which I'm calling the strip method to remove the leading and trailing whitespace. e.g.

```
s = "12345 "
s.strip
```

However if the string is <strike>empty</strike> `nil` I get the following error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9 so whats the easiest way to check if the value is `nil` before calling the strip method?

**Update:**

I tried this on an element in an array but got the same problem:

```
data[2][1][6].nil? ? data[2][1][6] : data[2][1][6].split(":")[1].strip
```

Comment: this has been asked in one way or another dozens of times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429790/is-there-a-clean-way-to-avoid-calling-a-method-on-nil-in-a-nested-params-hash

Comment: note to original poster: the String is not empty as you claim, which would be `s = ""`, it is nil. It doesn't yet exist. If it was empty you could check with: `s.strip unless s.empty?`

Comment: If the string is empty, you wouldn't get that error.

Comment: For your second question, add [`dig`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34623680/513951): `data.dig(2, 1, 6)&.split(":")[1]&.strip`. If any part of the data is missing or ill-formed, the whole expression returns `nil` with no error.

Answer (score 134):

[Ruby 2.3.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released/) added a *safe navigation operator* (`&.`) that checks for nil before calling a method.

```
s&.strip
```

If `s` is `nil`, this expressions returns `nil` instead of raising `NoMethodError`.

Comment: Yes - this is the only way to make Ruby act somewhat like a proper web-scripting language.  If only there were a way to set this globally for all cases where this annoying and useless behavior appears - and to "implicitly convert" all values to strings by default, where needed (like puts statements).

Comment: First time I've seen this- super useful

Comment: @JosephK: Have you used Ruby? `IO#puts` indeed calls `to_s` on all of its arguments, eg. `puts(5)`. Also, try `class NilClass; def method_missing(*a);nil;end;end`

Comment: I cannot count the number of times I have gotten failures on summing elements, puts, etc due to Ruby not behaving like Ecmascript would behave - make the sensible choice - given there are rarely cases where "nil" should not be treated as "" or zero (depending on context).

Comment: @JosephK `nil` (or `null`) has been called, among other things, [the worst mistake of computer science](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2015/08/31/the-worst-mistake-of-computer-science/).

Answer (score 17):

You can use method `try` from ActiveSupport (Rails library)

```
gem install activesupport

require 'active_support/core_ext/object/try'
s.try(:strip)
```

or you can use my gem [tryit](https://github.com/sevenmaxis/tryit) which gives extra facilities:

```
gem install tryit

s.try { strip }
```

Answer (score 11):

If you don't mind the extra object being created, either of these work:

```
"#{s}".strip
s.to_s.strip
```

Without extra object:

```
s && s.strip
s.strip if s
```

Answer (score 9):

I guess the easiest method would be the following:

```
s.strip if s
```

Comment: Not really convenient if you try to chain things.

Comment: What is needed is a way to universally say, "If I call a method on nil, just return nil" so we don't have to clutter up our code with this stuff.  IOW, we need "scripting language" functionality.  Maybe throw something into the console at dev-level, just to help troubleshoot if/when you get nil unexpectedly.

Comment: @JosephK Check out Jessie Sielaff's answer. What you're looking for was added in Ruby 2.3. It's called the _safe navigation operator_.

Comment: @lukad - Thanks.  Now if there was just a way to make this the default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I'd opt for a solution where `s` can never be `nil` to start with.

You can use the `||` operator to pass a default value if `some_method` returns a falsy value:

```
s = some_method || '' # default to an empty string on falsy return value
s.strip
```

Or if `s` is already assigned you can use `||=` which does the same thing:

```
s ||= '' # set s to an empty string if s is falsy
s.strip
```

Providing default scenario's for the absence of a parameters or variables is a good way to keep your code clean, because you don't have to mix logic with variable checking.

Answer (score 2):

Method which works for me (I know, I should never pollute pristine `Object` space, but it's so convenient that I will take a risk):

```
class Object
  def unless_nil(default = nil, &block)
    nil? ? default : block[self]
  end
end

p "123".unless_nil(&:length) #=> 3
p nil.unless_nil("-", &:length) #=> "-"
```

In your particular case it could be:

`data[2][1][6].unless_nil { |x| x.split(":")[1].unless_nil(&:strip) }`

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveSupport` comes with a method for that : `try`. For example, `an_object.try :strip` will return `nil` if `an_object` is nil, but will proceed otherwise. The syntax is the same as `send`. Cf [active_support_core_extensions.html#try](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#try).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the error that appears in the question:

```
s.to_s.strip
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete the options shown here, there is the "Existence Check Shorthand", [recommended in the Ruby Style Guide](https://rubystyle.guide/#double-amper-preprocess):

> Use `&&=` to preprocess variables that may or may not exist. Using `&&=` will change the value only if it exists [means, is not `nil`], removing the need to check its existence with `if`.

So in your case you would do:

```
s = "12345 "
s &&= s.strip
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

```
s = s.nil? ? s : s.strip
```

Tl;dr Check if s is nil, then return s, otherwise, strip it.

Comment: @lukad has a simpler answer than this even though.

Comment: Thanks - Just tried this on an element within an array combined with split. It still seems to fail though:
.
puts data[2][1][6].nil? ? data[2][1][6] : data[2][1][6].split(":")[1].strip
.
NoMethodError: undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass

Comment: What does `data[2][1][6].split(":")` return? Seems like it has only one item.