# Wildcard for nested params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way I can test for both these params to be `true`? Some sort of wildcard value for the first key?

```
params[:book][:return_to]
params[:work][:return_to]
```

At the moment I'm having to do:

```
if params[:book] and params[:book][:return_to]
   # blah
elsif params[:work] and params[:work][:return_to]
   # blah
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a clean way to avoid calling a method on nil in a nested params hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429790/is-there-a-clean-way-to-avoid-calling-a-method-on-nil-in-a-nested-params-hash)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, I think -- it's not that I want to check params[:book] && params[:return_to] like in the other question -- I want to check params[:anything_at_all][:return_to].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid NoMethodError for missing elements in nested hashes, without repeated nil checks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371716/how-to-avoid-nomethoderror-for-missing-elements-in-nested-hashes-without-repeat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashie is the solution I've used.

https://github.com/intridea/hashie

From their readme:

```
user = {
  name: { first: 'Bob', last: 'Boberts' },
  groups: [
    { name: 'Rubyists' },
    { name: 'Open source enthusiasts' }
  ]
}

user.extend Hashie::Extensions::DeepFind

user.deep_find(:name)   #=> { first: 'Bob', last: 'Boberts' }
```